# With iPadOS and the discontinuation of the iPod Touch, do I now *need* an iPhone to release iOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipados

This space is a lot more fragmented then when I left it.

I have a Macbook for the actual development and I'm eyeballing an iPad for builds and physical testing (the sensors I really care about are on both iPad and iPhone). Will this be enough? I don't need two phones and I'm not made of money.

Answer (score 0):

iPad is enough, no need of iPhone. To release iOS application, you don't need a device. But as you said you are doing physical testing, so iPad is enough. You can check functionality on iPad and to check UI, you can always use iPhone simulators.